# How will you give NFT as reward after Staking?

Tags: nft, staking

I'm working on a smart contract for a staking dApp. I have two ERC20 tokens **S** and **R**. Let's say **S** is a staking token, and  **R** is a reward token. I also have one ERC721 token. It is called **NFT Token**. So the user stakes 100 **S** tokens for seven days, and then he claims 20 **R** tokens as a reward. So that you know – the scenario implemented above works just fine.

I want to implement another reward scenario for the staking. The user who stakes the tokens over seven days can claim the **NFT Token** after 30 days as a reward.

Do you know how I can implement it? What is the logic so the user can return and claim the **NFT Token** after 30 days? The user has already claimed his staking rewards in **R** tokens.

Where would I store **NFT Token** rewards pending claims? What process would you suggest for the user to claim awarded **NFT Token** after the waiting period completion?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possible implementation is to mint the NFT token at the same time the R tokens are minted, but moving them to a vault contract with a 30 days time lock.

After the additional 30 days the NFT tokens could be withdraw from the vault contract.

Answer (score 1):

create a NFT minting  contract that handles  the minting  of  the nft at the cost of however many R tokens would be earned in a 30 day period

I.E if the user earns 30 R tokens over staking for 30 days they would spend 30 R tokens to mint the NFT